# How to get a value array from an object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

How can I access all values with the same key in an object array?
Given the following data:

```
data = [{first_name: 'Peter', last_name: 'Smith', age: 45}, 
        {first_name: 'John', last_name: 'Miller', age: 21}];
```

Is there a easy way to get an array containing all first names, like `first_names = ['Peter', 'John']`?

I guess I'm asking a very frequently asked question, but I couldn't find a solution anywhere to answer it.

Comment: Familiarize yourself on [how to access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/4642212) and use some of the [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Methods_of_the_Object_constructor) and [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods) methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The **[map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** method creates a new array with the results of calling a
>   provided function on every element in the calling array.

```js
data = [{
    first_name: 'Peter',
    last_name: 'Smith',
    age: 45
  },
  {
    first_name: 'John',
    last_name: 'Miller',
    age: 21
  }
];

var first_names = data.map(ele => ele.first_name);

console.log(first_names)
```